# iframe refresh issue

Tags: jsf, iframe

I am using JSF 1.2, and I have an iframe-refresh problem as follows.

thanks in advance,
mehmet

### 1) Main.jsp :

…

```
<div id="divIframe" style="…">
  <iframe id="w_iframe" src="#{SessionBean1.w_iframe}" style="…">                             
          <p> ;o) </p>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

### 2) #{SessionBean1.w_iframe} is loaded with :

"Company.jsp"

### 3) Inside w_iframe = Company.jsp (session-scoped bean) :

```
<div id="…" style="…">
   <h:dataTable id="sirket" value="#{Company.sirketModel}" var="currentR" style="…">
      <Columns…/>
   </h:dataTable>
</div>

<h:commandButton    id="w_save"   action="#{Company.event_handler_save}" style="…"    
                    value="#{SessionBean1.w_SAVE_txt}"/>
```

### 4) PROBLEM :

When clicking on the w_save button, the Company.jsp,

a)  Firefox and Chrome : renders h:dataTable and w_save button all the time without a problem.

b)  Internet Explorer 8 : renders some times without a problem, sometimes only w_save button. When refreshing page with F5, h:dataTable shows up, too.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is uglier than the problem, unfortunately :o(

```
<div id="…" style="**width / height / location : do not use % but px**">
   <h:dataTable id="sirket" value="#{Company.sirketModel}" var="currentR" style="…">
      <Columns…/>
   </h:dataTable>
</div>
```